# Remove max-width on audio player in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I'd like the default HTML5 audio player to fit the width of its parent container. I set its display to 'block' and width to '100%'. However, it seems like Chrome starts to add padding on the left and right sides after surpassing a certain window size:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox is behaving as I'd like it to, with the edges of the player reaching exactly to the edge of the parent div:

[image: Firefox]

How can I remove this extra padding in Chrome??

EDIT:: As pointed out in the comments, it looks like it's actually a max-width (not padding)...

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Just using an audio tag inside the body is enough... here's the fiddle... problem is the fiddle window is smaller than normal so you have to make the browser window really large to see... http://jsfiddle.net/3qLbdrka/

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3qLbdrka/3/, what I find out is, if you have a container larger than 800px the audio tag will stop growing on width

Comment: Exactly... that's the max-width behaviour in Chrome I'd like to disable. Like in Firefox it continues to grow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `max-width: 800px` in the shadow DOM:
[image]

You can use `::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure` to override it:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    max-width: 100%; /*or inherit*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3qLbdrka/4/

Answer (score 0):

There is chromium issue [138419](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138419) marked as "WontFix". The reason is that this is by design. 
Developers would have to design their own custom UI for special cases like yours (there could be a way to override this in CSS though).