# Clickable "positioning" hyperlinks to A/V (locally stored on your website and “hidden” behind a poster image)

Tags: html, media-player

***Meta***: *This question is a follow-up, or a variant of a similar question about embedded Youtube videos: [How to target "hidden" iframes? (application: links to starting positions of a "poster image hidden"-embedded Youtube video)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013991/how-to-target-hidden-iframes-application-links-to-starting-positions-of-a)*

---

*Definitions:*

## A "poster" image

A customized image on which you click, to reveal the actual A/V player.

## Locally stored

The A/V is stored on your website, as opposed to a streaming service such as Youtube.

## Clickable "positioning" hyperlinks

When a certain hyperlink inside an HTML text, a predefined starting (and perhaps ending) position of the A/V is addressed and automatically played.

---

I have been reading things on the net about `function(){something.currentTime=...;});`, but I have not been able to implement this.

Comment: I'll answer it as soon as I get some more free time, see you!

Comment: @Rou - Thanks, that would be very welcome, I could really use your help. As I think could the world in general, since it is hard to even find 1 source clearly stating the procedure.

Comment: Sorry, I've been swamped with work, maybe later today! :)

Comment: @Rou - I have been happily using your solution over the last couple of weeks. Unfortunately, my webhosting doesn't allow to store these "large" `.mp3-files` for a long amount of time... Cf. [Files (±50MB, audio) automatically repetitively deleted (after ± a couple of hours-days?)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145932/files-%C2%B150mb-audio-automatically-repetitively-deleted-after-%C2%B1-a-couple-of-hou?noredirect=1#comment176025_145932). Any good streaming hosting service you know of? If not, I think I will have to convert to a video, and stream them from youtube  nevertheless...

Comment: I can't seem to do it with [`Google Drive`](https://www.google.com/drive/) nor with [`Dropbox`](https://www.dropbox.com/). They don't seem to offer streaming that works with this solution. Perhaps a solution could be to once more use your other code at [How to target "hidden" iframes? (application: links to starting positions of a "poster image hidden"-embedded Youtube video)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013991/how-to-target-hidden-iframes-application-links-to-starting-positions-of-a)? :) Hmmm ... Very unfortunate these web serving limits, since your code was working so fine.

Comment: If you are looking for a video host well, youtube is the way to go, they also have an [**api**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos) if you want to upload the videos via scripting :)

Comment: @Rou - Hi! I'm now referring to `.mp3-files` specifically, but I could of course add some black video to them. But then still, I don't know how to get the Youtube video (or more relevant: audio) to stream via the HTML5 audio player you implemented in the project beow. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you tried the [**sound cloud api**](https://developers.soundcloud.com/)? I'm not an expert but It may be useful, again this is not my area of expertise :) Good luck!

Comment: Glad I could help! See you :)

Comment: @Rou - Edit: Thanks a lot for the tip. It works like a charm. Your code stays perfectly functional with the download link of an audio-file on [`Soundcloud`](http://soundcloud.com/). :) By similar quick tweaking, I haven't found a solution for `Google Drive`. Nor did I found 1 for `Dropbox` (I thought I had, but figured out this only functioned when logged in). Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Demo

I'm sorry for the delay, and for it not being exactly the same as the Youtube one, the thing I lack most it's consistency, but [**here it is**](http://jsfiddle.net/qudx64so/22/).

I've based this example in two songs from [**Hozier**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwAam3W_VLfb6mEKPW2nDFg), one in audio and one in video format. (Hope nobody sues me)

As always you can modify the styles later on to fit your design, I just put something quick together to demonstrate.

Below, you will see a basic example of how the code works (for a more in-depth example, please refer to the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qudx64so/22/)).

### HTML

#### Audio

```
<div class="mediaAudioFacade"
     id="id"
     data-sources="source1.mp3,source2.wav,source3.ogg"
     data-start="seconds"(optional)
     data-end="seconds"(optional)>
label
</div>

<div class="mediaJumper" data-id="id" data-time="seconds">label</div>
```

#### Video

```
<div class="mediaVideoFacade" (..)>(..)</div>
(..)
```

The only difference would be the class attribute, this being `mediaVideoFacade` instead of `mediaAudioFacade`.

### JavaScript

```
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    setUpMediaObjects();
    setUpMediaJumpers();
});
MediaObjects = [];
MediaJumpers = [];

function setUpMediaObjects() {
    var allAudioFacades = document.querySelectorAll(".mediaAudioFacade");
    if (allAudioFacades) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allAudioFacades.length; i++) {
            var facade = allAudioFacades[i];
            var mo = new MediaObject(facade);
            MediaObjects.push(mo);
        }
    }

    var allVideoFacades = document.querySelectorAll(".mediaVideoFacade");
    if (allVideoFacades) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allVideoFacades.length; i++) {
            var facade = allVideoFacades[i];
            var mo = new MediaObject(facade);
            MediaObjects.push(mo);
        }
    }
}

function setUpMediaJumpers(){
    var allMediaJumpers = document.querySelectorAll(".mediaJumper");
    for( var i = 0 ; i < allMediaJumpers.length ; i ++ ){
        var mediaJumper = allMediaJumpers[i];
        var mj = new MediaJumper(mediaJumper);
        MediaJumpers.push(mj);
    }
}


function MediaObject(facade) {
    this.facade = facade;
    this.id = this.facade.id;
    this.sourcesURI = this.facade.dataset.sources.split(",");
    this.sources = this.getSources();
    var isAudio = this.facade.className.match(/mediaAudioFacade/);
    this.type = (isAudio) ? "audio" : "video";
    this.icon = new Image();
        this.icon.src = (isAudio) ? "http://i.imgur.com/HKktAoE.png" : "http://findicons.com/icon/download/566082/video_play/33/png";
        this.setUpFacade();
    this.capType = this.type.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.type.substr(1);
    this.elem = document.createElement(this.type);
    this.elem.controls = "true";
    this.elem.className = "mediaType".replace(/type/i, this.capType);
    this.hasStarted = false;
    this.appendSources();
    this.startTime = this.facade.dataset.start;
    this.endTime = this.facade.dataset.end;
    this.facade.addEventListener("click", this.startUp.bind(this) );
}

MediaObject.prototype.setUpFacade = function () {
    var label = document.createElement("span");
    label.innerHTML = this.facade.innerHTML || "Play audio.";
    this.facade.innerHTML = "";
    this.facade.appendChild(this.icon);
    this.facade.appendChild(label);
}

MediaObject.prototype.getSources = function () {
    var sources = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sourcesURI.length; i++) {
        var sourceURI = this.sourcesURI[i];
        var source = document.createElement("source");
        source.src = sourceURI;
        sources.push(source);
    }
    return sources;
}

MediaObject.prototype.appendSources = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sources.length; i++) {
        var source = this.sources[i];
        this.elem.appendChild(source);
    }
}

MediaObject.prototype.startUp = function () {
    this.replaceNode(this.facade, this.elem);
    this.hasStarted = true;
    if( this.startTime )
        this.elem.currentTime = this.startTime;
    if( this.endTime )
        this.elem.addEventListener("timeupdate",this.checkForVideoEnd.bind(this));
    this.elem.play();
}

MediaObject.prototype.checkForVideoEnd = function(){
    console.log(this.elem.currentTime);
    if( Math.floor(this.elem.currentTime) == this.endTime )
        this.elem.pause();
}

MediaObject.prototype.replaceNode = function(node1,node2){
    var parent = node1.parentNode;
    var next = node1.nextSibling;
    if( next )
        parent.insertBefore(node2,next);
    else
        parent.appendChild(node2);
    parent.removeChild(node1);
}

function MediaJumper(jumper){
    this.jumper = jumper;
    this.id = this.jumper.dataset.id;
    this.mediaObject = this.getMediaObject();
    this.time = this.jumper.dataset.time;
    this.jumper.addEventListener("click",this.jump.bind(this));
}

MediaJumper.prototype.getMediaObject = function(){
    for( var i = 0 ; i < MediaObjects.length ; i ++ ){
        var mediaObj = MediaObjects[i];
        if( mediaObj.id == this.id )
            return mediaObj;
    }
    return null;
}

MediaJumper.prototype.jump = function(){
    if( this.mediaObject ){
        if( !this.mediaObject.hasStarted )
            this.mediaObject.startUp();
        this.mediaObject.elem.currentTime = this.time;
        this.mediaObject.elem.play();
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask any question's about the code, or report anything that is not working, good luck and hope it helps! :)

## Updates

- Added a `data-start` and `data-end`, note that `data-end` will only stop the video if the time specified matches the current time of the video floored. Technically:

  if( Math.Floor(MediaCurrentTime) == DataEndTime ) stop();

This means if a jumper is called it will continue to play normally until it hits that number again, and if the jumper calls for a time beyond the data-end, then the video will be played normally.

Comment: Wow! My first question would be: where did you learn this? --- Your Fiddle works great, thank you very much! No delay at all. --- Your help is very much appreciated indeed, I will use this for science. An exquisitely helpful and excellent coder, you are. --- Thank you for your effort in sharing your knowledge in an open way.

Comment: Thanks! You can learn more about the HTML5 audio and video elements [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video), I was wondering though didn't you need a `data-start` and `data-end` in the facades? Or was that only for the youtube one? :)

Comment: You are right, something like `data-end` might come in handy. I was just enthusiastically fiddling with your result, that I forgot about that. --- A small improvement may be to change the `div`s to `span`s, since I couldn't get the `mediaJumper`s inline when they were `div`s.

Comment: To get them as inline you could add `display:inline-block` in the CSS, or change it to a span as you did (span is displayed as an inline-block by default). I'll do when I come home from work, see you!

Comment: Yes, you are right, normally display: `inline-block` works just fine, as well as in your Fiddle. However, on my Drupal article, the `span` was the only solution ... couldn't figure out why. --- Now, for my current implementation, I am trying to make the `mediaAudioFacade` have a position: fixed at the bottom of the document, but it is very difficult to get the desired `100%` (minus `40 px` on both `left` and `right`), across all major browsers; because *Chrome* seems to work with a smaller HTML5 audio player, it seems to almost exactly (±`3px`) double the "margins".

Comment: For *Chrome*, it seems very hard to get the horizontal *CSS* margins, described in the comment above, right. Even with extra *Chrome*-specific *CSS* in between `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){`...`}`, as described in [Is there a Google Chrome-only CSS hack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812093/is-there-a-google-chrome-only-css-hack), but I'm not sure if *Safari*'s *CSS* will get changed along. --- It might be because I am not an experienced coder, but I find *Chrome* having a lot of room for improvements. E.g. it can also not handle RSS feeds very well.

Comment: It seems like the hack is webkit, so it should work in other webkit browsers like Safari and Opera :)

Comment: I've updated the answer and the fiddle to support `data-start` and `data-end` attributes, hope it helps! :)

Comment: Nice improvement, it works fine! --- I am not in the need for this, but it could be handy if every `<div class="mediaJumper" `...`>` could specify its own `data-start` and a `data-end`, like in your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhmo9j1a/12/) for embedded Youtube videos. --- In your current code for locally stored A/V, it seems `data-time` can already be replaced by `data-start`, however `data-end` has no defined function in the `<div class="mediaJumper" `...`>`'s there yet.

Comment: **I have found a fix for the *Chrome* issue.** The discussion that offered a solution is this one: [Remove max-width on audio player in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221047/remove-max-width-on-audio-player-in-chrome?rq=1). --- One should just add `.mediaAudio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {max-width: inherit}` in the *CSS*.

Comment: Hey @undefined. You are the one who kick-started my projects with your enormous help. How are you doing? ||| I would like to ask you the following: I now use: `<span class="MediaJumper" ...` to call for your audio script. How about if I would like to shorten this to e.g. `<span class="audio" ...` or even `<span class="_" ...`? I have tried to e.g. change the `.mediaJumper` in your script to `.audio`, but this has somehow disabled the script. =)